# Dynamic generics in Scala

Tags: generics, scala

I'm using a [3rd party library](https://github.com/codahale/jerkson), and the signature of a method is:

```
def parse[A](input: String)(implicit mf: Manifest[A]): A = ...
```

I only know `A` at runtime. How do I call the `parse` method above with `A` represented as a string?

Is the only option matching against all my domain objects?

E.g.

```
object ParserHelper {
  def apply(clazz: String, arg: String) = clazz match {
    case "DomainObjectA" => parse[DomainObjectA](arg)
    case "DomainObjectB" => parse[DomainObjectB](arg)
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Domain class %s not mapped" format clazz)
  }
}
```

...and then calling `ParserHelper("com.example.DomainObjectA", "some argument")` ?

I.e. how do I call `parse[???]("")` where ??? is dynamically constructed at run-time from a string like `"com.example.SomeDomainObject"`?

Comment: generics are a compile time type checking mechanism. Generating a generic type at runtime doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: is the manifest different per type? if so you can *try* to create a map<string,manifest> where the key is the classname and pass the manifest param explicitly to parse[?](arg,manifest). I don't actually know if that will work, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Kevin. See my comment to the accepted answer. I've been looking at this monitor for too long :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. You need to know something [A] at compile time that you only know at runtime.

Comment: This is true, and I realised "HOW would I parse something at runtime that I NEED to have knowledge of (at compile time)", so I may as well go ahead and flesh out the ParserHelper with all my domain objects, which luckily isn't countless :)

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you neeed to pass the manifest explicitely: I guess you can at least get hold of some `Class[_]` (`Class.forName`, or anything based on your `clazz` argument). You can build a manifest with `ClassManifest.classType(theClass)`. You get a `Manifest[_]`.

Then you just have to make a routine that will accept a `Manifest[_]`

```
def parseUntyped(input: String, m: Manifest[_]) = parse(input)(m)
```

`parse(input)(m)` is properly typed. Given that m if a manifest of some type, the call is correct. Of course, the return type of `parseUntyped` is `Any` and you will have to cast it back to what you want.

Comment: +1 This works brilliantly, thanks. Now I can just add new domain classes as strings to a map without having to have all of them on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Make these classes extend a trait and use that trait as your type parameter.  Remember, types are compile-time in Scala.  Pretending otherwise will make you and/or your code go crazy.